# Interpreting Phonon calculations for 2D materials

Tags: vibrations, phonopy, terminology, phonon-density-of-state, phonon-dispersion

What is the meaning of phonon calculation in 2D materials? And is it enough to predict the stability of materials based on positive phonon only?

Comment: Have you seen these prior questions about phonon interpretation and their relation to stability? https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/how-to-deduce-phase-transitions-from-a-phonon-calculation, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/what-do-negative-phonon-frequencies-signify, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/89/are-there-differences-in-accuracy-and-reliability-between-the-frozen-phonon-meth, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1779/phonon-calculations-and-vibrational-modes

Comment: This question seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments or if someone would like to provide an answer.